# CollapsingToolbarLayout mudar e deixar transparente

Tags: android

Não estou conseguindo trocar a cor do CollapsingToolbarLayout
Quando rolo para cima ele fica a imagem que coloquei e não troca a cor.

Antes:

[image: CollapsingToolbarLayout Normal]

Depois:

[image: CollapsingToolbarLayout depois]

Queria tirar a imagem e deixar o toolbar transparente.

Comment: Coloque na pergunta o xml que está a usar .

Comment: Pode mostrar como fez? Ajuda o pessoal a te ajudar! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode adicionar o [**`contentScrim`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html#attr_android.support.design:contentScrim) ao [**`CollapsingToolbarLayout`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html) e deixar o fundo da barra de ferramentas transparente, porém com opacidade, ou se preferir com uma cor sólida. Como você não colocou nenhum código, seria algo nesse formato:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/image"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

#### Um GIF vale mais que mil imagens

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como é mostrado na imagem acima, a cor do `Toolbar` está sólida. Para que fique transparente, basta alterar o valor de `contentScreem` para uma cor que tenha opacidade. Por exemplo `app:contentScrim="#77000000"`. Veja a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]